# CreateProcess command line arguments

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I am having a bit of problem using `CreateProcess()`.

In this example, `CreateProcess()` works perfectly fine:

```
bSuccess = CreateProcess(
                TEXT("os-util.exe"), 
                TEXT("os-util.exe 0x273e:0x0007:0x0100 --get-channel"), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 
                0,  
                NULL, szFileName, &si, &pi);
```

The problem is that I want to modify the command line that I pass. I tried a few solutions, but they didn't give me any good results. For example:

```
LPWSTR cmdArgslistSetChannel[] = { TEXT("os-util.exe"), TEXT("0x273e:0x0007:0x0100"), TEXT("--set-channel"), TEXT("11") };
bSuccess = CreateProcess(
                TEXT("os-util.exe"),
                cmdArgslistSetChannel, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 
                0,  
                NULL, szFileName, &si, &pi);
```

1. how can I change just part of the `TEXT("")`?
2. how can I make the command line from more than one `TEXT("")`?

If none of these options are available, what can be done? I want a UI button push to call `CreateProcess()` with different command line arguments.

Comment: Why are you using TEXT in the first place. Do you really need to support Windows 98? Why don't you go with the times and use Unicode?

Comment: `cmdArgslistSetChannel` must be `PWSTR` but not `PWSTR*` like in you code. so your question how format string ?

Comment: Looks like you would just need to append to your string? That should be easy. And if you check the [documentation for CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), it does not accept an array of strings in the second parameter, so not sure what you are even trying there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan give example. How would you write this line.

Comment: As I recall the command argument to `CreateProcess` must be mutable. Changing a literal is Undefined Behavior. So, use e.g. `std::wstring`.

Comment: I have channel list in combo box and i want to select channel from 1-12. i could just replace string. but i thought maybe there is a better way how to change just argv[3] in the string instead.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf i will try, ty

Comment: I ask you again, why are you using TEXT? Do you really need to target Windows 98? Why did you decide to write the code that way? My guess is you copied an example without understanding it. Next step: gain that understanding.

Comment: @David Heffeman yes, I saw example with it. i used it and it worked. so by that time i didnt need to change it to anything else. i am new in programing so i don't know all the possible ways. if i find something i try it.

Comment: Well, I'd say it's time to learn about Unicode in Windows and understand why you don't need TEXT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::wstring` and string concatenations to build up your command line dynamically, eg:

```
std::wstring cmdArgslistSetChannel = L"os-util.exe";
cmdArgslistSetChannel += L" 0x273e:0x0007:0x0100";
cmdArgslistSetChannel += L" --set-channel";
cmdArgslistSetChannel += L" 11";
bSuccess = CreateProcessW(
                L"os-util.exe",
                &cmdArgslistSetChannel[0],
                NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0,  
                NULL, szFileName, &si, &pi);
```

Alternatively, use `std::wostringstream` for the buildup, and then retrieve a `std::wstring` from it:

```
std::wostringstream cmdArgslistSetChannel;
cmdArgslistSetChannel << L"os-util.exe";
cmdArgslistSetChannel << L" " << L"0x273e:0x0007:0x0100";
cmdArgslistSetChannel << L" " << L"--set-channel";
cmdArgslistSetChannel << L" " << L"11";

std::wstring cmd = cmdArgslistSetChannel.str();
bSuccess = CreateProcessW(
                L"os-util.exe",
                &cmd[0],
                NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0,  
                NULL, szFileName, &si, &pi);
```

Either way, you can then replace any individual substring as needed.

Comment: It's very uncommon to pass both *lpApplicationName* as well as *lpCommandLine* to `CreateProcess`. The only time when this makes sense is, if you don't want to pass the executable image as the first command line argument. Since you are implementing the standard C convention to pass the executable image as the first command line argument, simply pass `nullptr` for *lpApplicationName*.